# Java Error acessing method of child class even when class is public

Tags: java

I have 2 classes Library and Books. The Class Library Extends Books

Class Library Contains a Public static method:-

```
 public static int getObjCount() {
    return objCount;
 }
```

I'm calling it from the class Books. like this:

```
int count = Library.getObjCount();
```

The code is crashing, This is the error log:

```
Books.java:172: error: cannot find symbol
                    int count = Library.getObjCount();
```

Comment: Is `objCount` also static?

Comment: yes it is static

Comment: show your classes

Comment: Library class: https://pastebin.com/R686VaHn
Books class: https://pastebin.com/YrAyzvW8

Comment: I have sent your code link have you got it?

Answer (score 1):

You should compile both classes together:

```
javac Books.java Library.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access child class method or member from the parent class. It isn't possible. This is because the parent class, `Books`, does not have access to the child class, `Library`.

But vice-versa is possible, since the child class derives from the parent class itself. Hence it has access to all non-private members of the parent class.

Comment: Can we do this
Parent extends child

Comment: and Child Extends parent at same time?

Comment: No @SuyashEkhande. i don't think it'd be possible. I guess you might have heard of the concept of overriding, where functions in parent and child classes, when having same names are called in child class, the child class method overrides the parent one. In case, this 2-way inheritance was made possible, it would create an immense amount of confusion.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest you to use the parent class, i.e, `Books` to just make a generalized version of any functionality you intend to implement overall. Any further refining or taking values and altering, do them in the child class. That's the whole point of using child classes anyway. by doing so, you'd be making more use of the inheritance concept as well.